# Responsive Layouts - Make a hidden div appear?

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm quite new to responsive layouts. I seem to have everything working in my favor except for one thing: I can't make divs with a `'display: none;'` property, appear when I set it to `'display: block;'` in my media query.

```
#test {
display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
   #test {

      display: block;
   }
}
```

Do I need jQuery for this?

Comment: Do you have an example somewhere on web? It should work like that, btw...

Comment: Just so you know, you don't REALLY need jQuery for anything. It's an amazing framework that makes things so much easier for the developers, but it doesn't do anything that plain javascript can't do

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't run as you might expect because the first rule has a specifity of `1 0 1`, while the second one has a specificity of `1 0 0`.

If you just write `#test`, instead of `div#test`, it will work, because when two rules have the same specificity, the last one is applied.

You can read more about CSS specificity here:

- http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/
- http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/04/07/css-specificity-and-inheritance/
- http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/specificity
- http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/understanding_c
- http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/quick-tip-understanding-css-specificity/
- http://www.standardista.com/css3/css-specificity/

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly selecting #test:

```
div#test { display: none; }

@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
   div#test { display: block; }
}​
```

A working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jvqra/

Comment: That's not a reason why its not working... It can also work like this : http://jsfiddle.net/jvqra/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#test {
  display: none;
}
```

It's useless to write `div#test`, because `#test` will always be unique. `div#test` will only slow down your performance (by like 0.000000000001s ;-) )

Demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/wpEwZ/

Comment: It is working with me

Less then 300px:
http://snag.gy/LCgEQ.jpg

Other sizes:
http://snag.gy/Y2lsn.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and you positively don't need any jquery. 
Test div will appear when the screen size is smaller than 320px, if you want opposite use min-width. Here is the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/jvqra/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS must specify "Important" for the div to appear

```
@media screen and (max-width:320px) {
  #test { block !important;}
}​
```